# I am working on shopping cart how can i remember the state of cart for user after he logs out using jwt

Tags: angular, spring, session, spring-security, shopping-cart

**using jwt**,how can i manage the **session** of shopping cart for user after he **logs out.**
to elaborate after user **logs in** and add some products in cart and **logs out**.how can i manage to see the **same products** in the cart after user logins again using JWT.what should be the approach using JWT or session?.can this problem be solved with JWT?

Comment: JWT _could_ do that, but it is not designed for such trivial purposes. Did you consider using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) ?

Comment: this thing should be maintained in database

Comment: hi florian and mustafa i am thinking about maintaining it in database,thanks for answering my question florian i was thinking about localstorage but i read somewhere that its not a safe option to store information in localstorage thats the reasoni asked the question in first place.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a matter of using or not JWT.

As you want to store this state in the database, you could create a pre-order state containing what's in the shopping cart, and whenever the user logs out and in, you can request the items on the pre-order state.

But there are a few things to consider here:

- The user can be browsing anonymously, so adding it to the `LocalStorage` is a good idea.
- The pre-order state must be cleared up after the order is confirmed so you don't show items that were already bought by the customer.

Comment: hii marcos i was thinking about persisting it in database but got overwhelmed because of many approach's being discussed on internet.thank you for your feedback.but could you elaborate your answer as in pre order state means what?creating a table for pre and post order in database or any other thing thanks.